# php set email user agent

Tags: php, email

I have an application that sends verification emails to people account email address, but sometimes it goes into their spam filter, after an analysis on the email we found that one of the reasons is because of having no user agent name.

is there a way to set this using php's default email sender?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a exhaustive "what to do if auto-generated mails get swallowed by the spam filter" a few years ago. Unfortunately, it's in german, but one aspect I remeber from the research I did for it is that spam filters can react very pickily to X-Mailer signatures that point towards a programming language / script / bulk E-Mailer. You may want to pretend to be a normal mail program like Outlook to make sure the E-Mail gets through.

Comment: this is what i would like to get information about, how would one go about this?

Comment: If I send an E-Mail to myself using Thunderbird, I get "User-Agent: Thunderbird 2.0.0.23 (Windows/20090812)" in the header. Outlook is sure to have a similar attribute. You might want to leave X-Mailer aside, try one of these and see whether they get through better.

Answer (score 1):

The only user agent setting in PHP is `user_agent`, but this setting is only used for HTTP requests. You can pass additional headers to the `mail()` function to accomplish this:

```
mail(
    'to@example.com',
    'Subject',
    'Message Body',
    "From: from@example.com\r\nX-Mailer: PHP"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a header that identifies your program. As you can see in the php manual for [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) the fourth paramter allows you to include headers. The RFC identifies both "Mailer", "X-Mailer" and "Sender" as the agents, so which one to use I will leave up to you ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_client) notes that X-Mailer is ofte used by clients).

An example:

```
$headers = "X-Mailer: MyApp\r\n";
$succcess = mail(€to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: What RFC identifies these header fields?  Not IMF (RFC 5322:  http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322).

Answer (score 0):

Headers like X-Mailer (all beginning with X-)
are extra headers, and do not define User Agent header.
You should define header: "User-Agent".
See sources your messages which you are sent from email client.